# Android TextWatcher when check radioButton

Tags: android, colors, textwatcher

I'm using TextWatcher to change the color of the text of the EditText.
I have 2 RadioButtons, I wish the color would change when selecting a radio button. For example, if I click on radio1 the text should turn red, however if I click the radio2 the color should be green. How do I call the Listner to radioButton?
This is my TextWatcher:

```
TextWatcher watcher= new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
                if (mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                    mIm.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#228b22"));
                }
                else {
                    mIm.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                }

            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                                    }
                };
        mIm.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are even using a `TextWatcher` here. What you need is [onCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) and change the text color in `onCheckedChange()` as you are now.

```
mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChange(RadioGroup group, int id)
    {
         switch (id)
         {
             case (R.id.radio1):
               mIm.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#228b22"));
               break;
             default:
             mIm.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
         }
   }
});
```

Comment: even though I have entered the code nell'onCreate (), the text color is changed only after a click on the RadioButton. startup is the default color and not the radio checked. thanks

Comment: Yes, it won't change until you click a `RadioButton`. You can check in `onCreate()` which is checked if you want with something like `RadioButton rbtn` = findViewById(); if (rbtn.isChecked) { mIm.setTextColor(blah);`

Answer (score 0):

TextWatcher is for watching text fields.  You need to handle the onClick for the button.  Something like this:

```
  @Override
  public void onClick (View v) 
  {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
      case R.id.red_text:
        mIm.setTextColor (Color....);
        break;
      case R.id.green_text:
        mIm.setTextColor (Color....);
        break;
    }
  }
```

Don't forget to set the OnClickHandler for the radio buttons.